# mvn clean command on my Mac OS throws me error

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, osx-mavericks

I am trying to delete documents which are created by doorstop and getting error as "Multiple Root documents" Please refer to below link for more information

https://github.com/doorstop-dev/doorstop/issues/293

Solution for that is to run "mvn clean" command but I am getting below error for "mvn clean" command. Any possible solutions regarding this.

```
(base) MANOJs-MacBook-Air:~ manojdeshpande$ mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.090 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-21T23:01:40+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/manojdeshpande). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

> The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no
>   POM in this directory (/Users/manojdeshpande). Please verify you
>   invoked Maven from the correct directory

The problem is that Maven can't find a pom file (pom.xml is the maven project configuration file) where you are running the maven clean command, so it's impossible for Maven to know what to do, even if you specified the clean goal.

Maybe your pom file is somewhere else than */Users/manojdeshpande*?